Cubic: Can I stop and restart a Cubic session
If I have started running a cubic session and have not completed the work necessary to complete the new custom ISO but have to shutdown my computer due to something like an impending thunderstorm, is it possible to end the cubic session and restart the cubic session at a later time.
If so, is there a procedure for stopping and restarting the cubic session without have to start from scratch?

On the Cubic Finish Page, If you want to delete all project working files (in order to save disk space) check the "Delete all project files..." checkbox. Although the generated *.iso file and corresponding *.md5 checksum file will not be deleted, you will not be able to continue customizing this project in the future.
However, if you chose to keep all project files, you will be able to continue customizing your project in the future.

https://github.com/PJ-Singh-001/Cubic/wiki/Finish-Page

You can exit Cubic at any time on any page. You can reopen your exiting project in the future to continue customizing it. Avoid exiting Cubic while executing a long running command on the Terminal page as this may mess up your work, but in most cases, you can simply just re-execute your command the next time you open Cubic.
